# Do fragment tab icons need to be specified for every screen size?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I provide images for every screen size(hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi) but do I have to do the same thing for fragment icons as well? (they are png format)

[image]

Comment: Yes you still need to provide a different resource unless you use Vector base image.

Comment: @Enzokie 48    Do these icons get resized? or they are fixed for different screen sizes?

Comment: Vector base image does not get distorted even if they are resized unlike with Raster image like .png .jpg

Comment: Yes Vectors are size independent. Now Android Studio comes with built-in Vector Asset Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I provide images for every screen size(hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi)

Those are not screen *sizes*. Those are screen *densities*.

> do I have to do the same thing for fragment icons as well?

I do not know what "fragment icons" are. I am guessing that perhaps you are referring to tabs, though it is difficult to tell from that screenshot.

Regardless, your objective is to have your icons look good on all screen densities. How many densities you provide directly — with the rest being generated by Android by resampling those you do provide — is up to you.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, I was referring to the tabs